# How can multilingual Titles and Categories be correctly shown in Quick Edit using Qtranslate-XT?

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, qtranslate

I use Qtranslate-XT for several multilingual Wordpress sites, and it works mostly well. One thing it doesn't do is to handle multilingual entries in the Quick Edit. Page and Post titles as well as category names show up in raw format with language markup ([:en]...). It should be noticed that things work nicely on the full-edit pages.

I have tried to understand from the integration guide if there is a way to fix this with JSON configuration files without diving into the code, but I have given up.